# Possible to Combine columns on id in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server and I need a query that will change a table I'm working with:

From  this

```
| Band Name | Guitar1       | Guitar2 | Drums     | Bass          | Vocals      |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| LedZep    | JimmyPage     | NULL    | NULL      | NULL          | NULL        |
| LedZep    | NULL          | NULL    | JonBonham | NULL          | NULL        |
| LedZep    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL      | JohnPaulJones | NULL        |
| LedZep    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL      | NULL          | RobertPlant |
```

"MAGIC SQL QUERY"

to this:

```
Band Name | Guitar1    | Guitar2 | Drums     | Bass         | Vocals      |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LedZep    | Jimmy Page | NULL    | JonBonham | JonPaulJones | RobertPlant |
```

Comment: Danny try to read your own question as it is formatted and see if it makes any sense to you? Also what RDBMS you are using? MySQL , SQL Server, Oracle ???

Comment: Removed the part about the db transfer, it's not relevant. I need a query that will out put the bottom statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may depend on what beckend server software you are using, but the basic idea would be:

```
SELECT 
    BandName,
    MAX(Guitar1) Guitar1,
    MAX(Guitar2) Guitar2,
    MAX(Drums) Drums,
    MAX(Vocals) Vocals
FROM Bands
GROUP BY BandName
```

However if a band has two records with a value for `Vocals` (or any column) what would you expect in the results?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sparse on details here but something this should work.

```
select BandName
    , MAX(Guitar1) as Guitar1
    , MAX(Guitar2) as Guitar2
    , MAX(Drums) as Drums
    , MAX(Bass) as Bass
    , MAX(Vocal) as Vocals
from SomeTable
group by BandName
```

Comment: hehe seems the same query got posted about 9 seconds before mine. D Stanley was faster on the keyboard. :D

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there is any benefit of using this approach over any other, I wrote the query so I though I will share, A rather complex solution than simply using MAX() and GROUP BY suggested by other two SO users :) . Anyway its always better to have a plan B in place :)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/38850)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE 
(BandName VARCHAR(20),Guitar1 VARCHAR(20),Guitar2 VARCHAR(20)
, Drums VARCHAR(20),Bass VARCHAR(20),Vocals VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES 
('LedZep1','JimmyPage1',   NULL  ,  NULL     ,  NULL     ,      NULL ),
('LedZep1',   NULL    ,   NULL  ,'JonBonham1',  NULL     ,      NULL ),
('LedZep1',   NULL    ,   NULL  ,  NULL     , 'JohnPaulJones1', NULL ),
('LedZep1',   NULL    ,   NULL  ,  NULL     ,  NULL          ,'RobertPlant1'),
('LedZep2','JimmyPage2',   NULL  ,  NULL     ,  NULL     ,      NULL ),
('LedZep2',   NULL    ,   NULL  ,'JonBonham2',  NULL     ,      NULL ),
('LedZep2',   NULL    ,   NULL  ,  NULL     , 'JohnPaulJones2', NULL ),
('LedZep2',   NULL    ,   NULL  ,  NULL     ,  NULL          ,'RobertPlant2')

SELECT * 
FROM @Table t
 UNPIVOT ( Vals FOR N IN (Guitar1, Guitar2, Drums, Bass, Vocals ))up
 PIVOT (MAX(Vals)
        FOR N 
        IN (Guitar1, Guitar2, Drums, Bass, Vocals )
        )p
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/38850/0)**:

```
| BANDNAME |    GUITAR1 | GUITAR2 |      DRUMS |           BASS |       VOCALS |
|----------|------------|---------|------------|----------------|--------------|
|  LedZep1 | JimmyPage1 |  (null) | JonBonham1 | JohnPaulJones1 | RobertPlant1 |
|  LedZep2 | JimmyPage2 |  (null) | JonBonham2 | JohnPaulJones2 | RobertPlant2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

This manages the case when there are more than one person per role:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE 
(BandName VARCHAR(20),Guitar1 VARCHAR(20),Guitar2 VARCHAR(20)
, Drums VARCHAR(20),Bass VARCHAR(20),Vocals VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES 
('LedZep','JimmyPage',   NULL  ,  NULL     ,  NULL     ,      NULL ),
('LedZep',   NULL    ,   NULL  ,'JonBonham',  NULL     ,      NULL ),
('LedZep',   NULL    ,   NULL  ,  NULL     , 'JohnPaulJones', NULL ),
('LedZep',   NULL    ,   NULL  ,  NULL     ,  NULL          ,'RobertPlant'),
('Other',   'Guitar',   NULL  ,  NULL     ,  NULL     ,      NULL ),
('Other',   NULL    ,   NULL  , 'Drums'     ,  NULL     ,      NULL ),
('Other',   NULL    ,   NULL  ,  NULL     , 'Bass', NULL ),
('Other',   NULL    ,   NULL  ,  NULL     ,  NULL          ,'Vocal1'),
('Other',   NULL    ,   NULL  ,  NULL     ,  NULL          ,'Vocal2')


SELECT DISTINCT BandName
    , STUFF((SELECT ','+Guitar1 
             FROM @table S2 
             WHERE S1.BandName = S2.BandName
             FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Guitar1
    , STUFF((SELECT ','+Guitar2 
             FROM @table S2 
             WHERE S1.BandName = S2.BandName
             FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Guitar2             
    , STUFF((SELECT ','+Guitar2 
             FROM @table S2 
             WHERE S1.BandName = S2.BandName
             FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Drums
    , STUFF((SELECT ','+Drums 
             FROM @table S2 
             WHERE S1.BandName = S2.BandName
             FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Bass            
    , STUFF((SELECT ','+Bass 
             FROM @table S2 
             WHERE S1.BandName = S2.BandName
             FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Vocals
    , STUFF((SELECT ','+Vocals 
             FROM @table S2 
             WHERE S1.BandName = S2.BandName
             FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Vocals          

FROM @table S1
```